# Multiple light sources in a tile-based lighting system

Tags: lua, roblox

I have made a rudimentary tile based lighting system in ROBLOX by changing color based on distance from lightsource. I want to be able to put multiple lightsources, but I've ran into some problems:

The performance goes down a bit (from full 60 to 45-50) when I try to add another light source.

It doesn't work correctly, the lightsources cut out eachother's light and such.

my code:

```
local sp = script.Parent
local lightBrightness
local lightPower = 1
local grid = game.ReplicatedStorage.Folder:Clone()
grid.Parent = workspace.CurrentCamera
local lightSource = game.ReplicatedStorage.LightSource:Clone()
lightSource.Parent = workspace.CurrentCamera
lightSource.Position = grid:GetChildren()[math.random(1,#grid:GetChildren())].Position
for _, v in pairs(grid:GetChildren()) do
    if v:IsA("Part") then
        game["Run Service"].RenderStepped:connect(function()
            local lightFact = (lightSource.Position-v.Position).magnitude
            lightBrightness = lightPower - (lightFact*10)/255
            if lightFact < 35 then
                v.SurfaceGui.Frame.BackgroundColor3 = v.SurfaceGui.Frame.BackgroundColor3.r >= 0 and Color3.new((100/255)+lightBrightness*.85,(50/255)+lightBrightness*.85,10/255+lightBrightness) or Color3.new(0,0,0)
            elseif lightFact > 35 and lightFact < 40 and v.SurfaceGui.Frame.BackgroundColor3.r > 0 then
                v.SurfaceGui.Frame.BackgroundColor3 = Color3.new(0,0,0)         
            end     
        end)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason your code is running slowly is because the `RenderStepped` event runs every frame render, which is (typically) every 1/60th of a second. Try using the `Stepped` event to improve performance, as it only fires ever 1/30th of a second.

As for your light sources cancelling each other out, it appears from looking over your code that each light source affects the tiles around it *without* checking what light sources were affecting the tile before.

For example, light source A has a `lightFact` of *37* affecting tile A, so tile A changes it's appearance. Then, light source B, which is later in the loop, has a `lightFact` of *32*. Well, the final `lightFact` value for that tile is going to be 32, effectively cancelling out the initial light sources effect.

In order to fix this issue, you need to store the current `lightFact` variable for each tile as you progress through the loop. My recommendation (alas, maybe not the fastest) would be to create a new `Instance` of `IntValue` inside of each tile, storing the current affecting `lightFact` value on the tile. Then, whenever a light source is about to check the tile, check if it has a child `lightFact`, and if it does, add that value to the `lightFact` value in your code. Therefore, the `lightFact` value you use to apply to the tile doesn't cancel out the last light source, because it incorporates that other lightsources `lightFact` value in its own calculation. Make sense?